# Shouldn't I get unique data when I fetch from Github API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, key

I have an application that display trending repositories from GitHub API.

I am using this function to fetch data, page increments every time I get to the bottom of the page:

```
function fetchMoreRepos() {
    const url = `https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:>2017-10-22&sort=stars&order=desc&page=${page}`;
    axios.get(url).then(res => setRepos([...repos, ...res.data.items]));
    setPage(page + 1);
    setIsFetching(false);
  }
```

I am using this line of code to render every repository:

```
return repos.map(item => <Repo repo={item} key={item.id} />);
```

The problem is that sometimes I don't get unique repositories when I get to another page which means `key="item.id"` is not unique and this gives me a warning in React.

Comment: @Daan It's using a template literal to embed `page` in the request URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why some results are appearing across `page` requests.

One guess is the order of trending repos is changing, causing a repo at the end of page 1 to drop a few places in the order, and it's pushed to the start of page 2. For example, repo #10 and repo #11 swap places, and if you're requesting 10 results per page, repo #10 is initially in the first page, then pushed to the 2nd page.

Anyway, a quick solution would be to combine `page` and `item.id` for the `key`. Something like:

```
key={`${page}-${item.id}`}
```

which should make the `key` unique.